# Replacing text on form submit using jQuery stays for few seconds and disappears later

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, xss

I have a form element and span element as below:

```js
//I have used following jQuery function to replace text in span:

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function () {
    var new_text = "Sorry, username '" + $("#username").val() + "' is taken already. Try another one. ";
    $("#name").text(new_text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="#form">
   <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
   <input class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" type="submit" id="btn">
</form>
            
<span id="name"></span>
```

On form submit, I want add the text to the span with id "name". But on form submit, the text flashes for few seconds.

I want the text to be present on the page and I also want ?username=name to be present in the url after form submit i.e, I want form input to be the part of url because I want to try DOM XSS attack on my page. I rendering the html file using a flask server.

Can anyone tell me how to make the text on the page without compromising the url to contain form input data?

Answer (score 0):

The text flashes for a few seconds because clicking the `.btn` button submits the form, which refreshes the page and removes and dynamic changes you made to the DOM since the page first loaded.

To keep the update you made to the text of the element you just need to call `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event of the `#form` element to stop the submission, and prevent the page reloading.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#form").on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_text = `Sorry, username '${$("#username").val()}' is taken already. Try another one`;
    $('#name').text(new_text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" type="submit" id="btn">
</form>

<span id="name"></span>
```

Note that from the context of the code and the message being shown, I would assume you would need to extend the logic by making an AJAX request to the server to check the validity and availability of the entered username. I will leave that as an exercise for the OP to complete.

Comment: Using preventDefault is helping the text part but I url parameter doesn't contain form input now. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That's because you aren't sending the information to the server any more. If you actually want to send the information to the server, then you will need to put the 'Sorry, username taken...' message in the page as it's rendered from the **server side**, not in Javascript/jQuery. I would also suggest you research the difference between the client side and server side logic.